# Google Apps domain using UserManager.getAllUsers() with CacheService

Tags: google-apps-script

On my College's Google Apps domain there are thousands of users but I need traverse them all to assign them to the correct Groups. Clearly, this would exceed the five mins time limit so I am trying to utilise the CacheService to handle this. The issue is that to store the object array, I need to jsonStringify it and jsonParse it back when the function restarts. But the jsonParse'd object fails because the object method getUserLoginId no longer exists. How else can I store the object array so it works? Am I missing something obvious?

```
function functname() {
  var users_all = check_cache('cachename');
  var num_done = 0;
  for(u in users_all) {
     Logger.log(users_all[u].getUserLoginId());
     users_all.shift();
     store_cache('cachename',users_all);
     Utilities.sleep(1000);
     num_done++;
     if(num_done > 100) //prevent timeout
     {
        break;
     }
  }
}

function check_cache(cacheKey) {
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
  var cachedString = cache.get(cacheKey);
  var lstData;
  if (cachedString == null) {
    lstData = UserManager.getAllUsers();
    cache.put(cacheKey, Utilities.jsonStringify(lstData));
    Logger.log('Cash NOT used');
  }
  else {
    lstData = Utilities.jsonParse(cachedString);
    Logger.log('Cash used' + lstData);
  }
  return lstData;
}

function store_cache(cacheKey, lstData) {
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
  var cachedString = cache.get(cacheKey);
  cache.put(cacheKey, Utilities.jsonStringify(lstData));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to stringify functions, only data. When you should do instead is create a custom object from the data in DomainUser, and stringify and parse that instead.